# Why is ui-sref='tango::new' sending a request to /tangos/new (plural)?

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

**HTML**

```
<a ui-sref='tango::new'>Create Tango</a>
```

**tango.routes.js**

```
angular
  .module('tango')
  .config(config)
;

function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('tango', {
      url: '/tango/:id',
      templateUrl: '/states/tangos/tango.html',
      controller: 'TangoController as vm'
    })
    .state('tango::new', {
      url: '/tango/new',
      templateUrl: '/states/tangos/tango.html',
      controller: 'TangoController as vm'
    })
  ;
}
```

This is the request that is going out when I click the link:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/tangos/new
```

Why is this? How can I stop it from happening?

Comment: never seen `::` notation used in router. Did you find that documented somewhere?

Comment: I made it up myself, it's not part of ui-router (to my knowledge).

Comment: making up syntax is bound to generate unexpected results. Answer to stop it happening is use valid syntax

Comment: Using `tango-new` instead of `tango::new` leads to the same problem (the reason why I was using `::` is because that syntax indicates a namespace, which is what I'm using).

Comment: create a demo , states use dot for nested states not `::`

Comment: Where is the documentation for `::`? I haven't seen that before, and with a cursory glance I still didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pgR9Q1S5N4QDcnA9k18G?p=preview)

The point here *(despite of a bit unusual state name tango::new - which is still absolutely valid)* is: the order of state definition:

> the first (sooner) must be defined more specific, the second (later) the more generic

So, this should be the proper order:

```
.state('tango::new', {
  url: '/tango/new',
  templateUrl: 'states/tangos/tango.html',
  controller: 'TangoController as vm'
})

.state('tango', {
  url: '/tango/:id',
  templateUrl: 'states/tangos/tango.html',
  controller: 'TangoController as vm'
})
```

With this order in place, these links will work:

```
//ui-sref
<a ui-sref='tango({id:1})'>tango({id:1})
<a ui-sref='tango({id:22})'>tango({id:22})
<a ui-sref='tango::new'>Create Tango

//href
<a href="#/tango/333">
<a href="#/tango/4444">
<a href="#/tango/new">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pgR9Q1S5N4QDcnA9k18G?p=preview)

Comment: That fixed it - thanks! I just looked it up so I understand it now, but you may want to include in your answer that when you go to a url, ui-router looks up the url and activates the corresponding state (I didn't know this; I thought all lookups were by state name, and that the order wouldn't matter). [Reference](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)